# LdapAuthenticationProvider not checking if user is not active

Tags: ldap, spring-security

I can auth my website with either ldap or by looking in db using different spring security authentication providers.

When i use the database auth, i use `UserDetailsService`, which correctly checks if my user is notActive and throws `DisabledException` correctly.

but using `LdapAuthenticationProvider` this does not occur. why?

**spring security 2.0.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which LdapAuthenticator are you using? If you use BindAuthenticator it will bind as the given user, eventually the directory server should reject if the user account disabled/expired.

I haven't used LdapAuthenticationProvider myself, but if its not done automatically you can retrieve the userdetails, The UserDetails class has bunch of methods to check weather the account is enabled/locked/expired.

Comment: right, its just sad that i need to do the check manually when i change the provider implementation. thats what i ended up doing anyway..